# Regular expression that accepts mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression which accepts date in mm/dd/yyyy format:

```
 /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/;
```

How to I change it so that it accepts date in mm/yyyy format too?

I've tried:

```
/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{0,2})\/(\d{4})$/;
```

but I can't get rid of the extra bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modifier `?` to make `/dd` optional:

```
/^(\d{1,2})(?:\/(\d{1,2}))?\/(\d{4})$/;
```

Comment: Thank you. I works now. I didn't know how to make it optional earlier

Comment: @Dell Welcome, you can tell this to community by accepting the answer. ;)